# Controlling LED strip from GPIO Help?

Tags: gpio, python, led

I have a ws2811 LED strip that I was powering using an arduino, but I want to do some more complicated things with it, and figured my old raspberry pi would be perfect.
So I followed a tutorial online and got it working... sort of
( https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/using-neopixels-with-the-raspberry-pi )

I have a simple python script that should loop though red green and blue every second, but when I run it, the code works fine (prints every second) but the strip seems to hang randomly, then start working again, or display half a color, just random glitches.

Im assuming it's something to do with the data out of the pi not being what the strip is expecting,
Does anyone have any ideas on this?

```
import time
import board
import neopixel

pixel_pin = board.D18
num_pixels = 5
ORDER = neopixel.GRB
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, num_pixels, brightness=0.2, auto_write=False, pixel_order=ORDER)

print("Start")

pixels.fill((0,0,0))
pixels.show()

time.sleep(1)

print("loop")

while True:
    print("red")
    for i in range(0,5):
        pixels[i] = (255,0,0)
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(1)

    print("green")
    for i in range(0,5):
        pixels[i] = (0,255,0)
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(1)

    print("blue")
    for i in range(0,5):
        pixels[i] = (0,0,255)
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: How many LED’s in your strip? Are they powered from a separate power supply?

Comment: currently using 5 leds
(well its 45, but they are in blocks of 3, so software wise its 5)
And yes running off separate 12v power

Comment: Have you got a common ground between Pi and 12V power?

Comment: I do not... that is a good thought,
I did when working on arduino, but not on the pi
Will give that a go.

Comment: Yep, that seems to have fixed it
Will add the rest of m code int he morning and see how it handles that

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have a common ground between the Pi, the LEDs and the power supply so that referenced voltages are consistent.

[image]